# Circle through an array of game objects killing the previous one on click c#

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-development

I have an array containing game objects and i want to instantiate the first one on click and if i click again, kill the current game object and instantiate the next game object in the array.

```
public Transform[] Cubes;
Transform Clone;
public Transform Spawnup;

void Start()
{
Clone = Instantiate(Cubes[Random.Range(0, 3)], transform.position, 
transform.rotation) as Transform;
Clone.parent = transform;

transform.position = Spawnup.position;


}

void FixedUpdate()
{
if (transform.childCount < 1)
{
transform.position = Spawnup.position;

Clone = Instantiate(Cubes[Random.Range(0, 3)], transform.position, 
transform.rotation) as Transform;
Clone.parent = transform;
}
}


private public void ChangeOnClick()
{
//Destroy(gameObject);

//for (int i = 0; i < Cubes.Length; i++)
// {
//    Clone = Instantiate(Cubes[0], Clone.position, Clone.rotation) as 
Transform;
// }

}

private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{
if (collision && transform.childCount > 0)

{
Clone.parent = Spawnup;
}
}
}
```

i tried using an int and ++ but every time i instantiated a game object on click, all the game objects got instantiated at once.

Answer (score 0):

The code that you have inside the FixedUpdate function should be inside the ChangeOnClick function.

### Code:

```
GameObject _PreviousClone;
int cubeIndex;

private public void ChangeOnClick()
{
if (transform.childCount < 1)
{
    transform.position = Spawnup.position;
   if(_PreviousClone && _PreviousClone.canBeDestroyed)
    {
    Destroy(_PreviousClone.gameobject);
    cubeIndex++;
    Clone = Instantiate(Cubes[cubeIndex], transform.position, 
    transform.rotation) as Transform;
    [yourClass] _cloneClass = Clone.getcomponent<[Yourclass]>();
    _cloneClass.canBeDestroyed = true;
    _PreviousClone = Clone;
    Clone.parent = transform;

       if(cubeIndex==Cubes.length-1)
         cubeIndex=0;
    }
}
}
```

Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Okay true so i have added the If statement checking if the child count is < 1. but how do i instantiate the next game object in the array? and if i click again the next game object? In my array i have 4 game objects and i want to keep cicling through (0,1,2,3....0,1,2,3...) everytime i click

Comment: I've added a rough psudo code in the edited answer. You can try with it. also, when the index reaches the array.length-1, you can reset it to 0.